# What is the best way to learn new things on Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, best-practices

I am trying to figure out the best way to learn new things on Stack Exchange, and  ultimately design a study plan to help myself and others. To this end, I'd like to hear how others use these websites to achieve this end.

I am a programmer, and thus naturally inclined to use Stack Overflow.

Here is what I currently do:

- I have a list of interested tags
- I try to read  questions  from each tag, as much as I can (sort of random)
- If a question that I can answer catches my eye, which happens rarely, I give it a shot
- I occasionally ask questions regarding problems I confront at work or encounter while reading technical books/articles or watching video lectures

I am not sure if this is an effective way to achieve my goal of learning new things on this site, and I want to refine it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Frequently I'll try to answer a question that I don't already know the answer too.  I'll go digging through google and documentation and stuff and see if I can get an answer that will help the asker.  Even if I'm unsure of it, I'll post it anyway.  If it's incorrect it gets down-voted and its no big deal, I wasn't planning on it being 100% correct anyway.  Then I'll go and read the up-voted answers to see what I did wrong/how it should have been answered.

This is actually how I taught myself how to program a few years back.

Plus, you get them right more frequently then you would expect.

Answer (score 3):

When I find an interesting question but don't know the answer to it, I'll research the answer. Once I've found a solution that works, I'll go back and refresh the page - usually, someone else will have posted an answer by that point, so I'll compare what I found with what they suggest - thereby learning both from my own research and that of others.

I'm absolutely terrible at asking questions, being much too impatient when it comes to finding answers for the problems I face day-to-day... Indeed, all but one of the questions I've asked on Stack Overflow were prompted by other questions on Stack Overflow. So I tend to avoid asking questions - there are plenty of people with real problems who can use the help.

I also try to spend a bit of time editing questions and answers. Plenty of folks struggle with English and/or Markdown and can use the help. A nice side-effect of this is that it exposes me to topics I'd otherwise avoid.

Comment: Agree with your second point. I, however, am completely different in relation to #1 - I post first, ask questions later. If I'm not totally sure, I Google it. Once, I answered a one-sentence question right, thought I had it wrong (edited it again), then rolled it back. Needless to say, the asker (who was watching carefully) got a bit confused :).